# create jar with intellij : "principal class unfindable or unloadable"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, packaging

I try to create a jar from my java project inside intellij, but I get this error.

I used the intellij wizard ("create jar from module with dependencies"), extracted the jar dependencies, and specified that the generated MANIFEST.MF should be located at java/main/resources.

here are some windows I got:

[image: here] here is the view of the decompiled jar; there is a META-INF directory, containing the MANIFEST.MF file. The main class is BookWindow; located in the view directory you can see above.

[image] here is the view directory, and

[image] here is the MANIFEST.MF file.

The error in french is:

> PS D:\docs\biblio2\out\artifacts\biblio2_jar3> java -jar .\biblio2.jar
>   Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale
>   view.BookWindow

and in the following 2 screenshots, you can view the artifact page of intellij idea:

[image: here]
[image]

What do I have wrong?

EDIT

Well, the full package name for BookWindow is, I think, "view"... I took another screenshot for this:

[image: here]

EDIT
I can run the program from intelliJ.
I moved the files inside the "com.*" directory to src/main/java but if I try to package it with maven now I get this error:

> COMPILATION ERROR [ERROR]
>   /D:/docs/biblio2/src/main/java/amazon/advertising/api/sample/SignedRequestsHelper.java:[28,39]
>   package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist

There are 2 classes inside the sub-directory of com.*, and it is used gain access to the amazon books database. in its "imports" the first line is:

> import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

before these 2 moves (there are 2 files) I was able to package the project with maven, I got a huge jar file with all the dependencies, but I was unable to run it : "java -jar myfile.jar" got a classNotFoundException, concerning the Flamingo class, which though was present in the lib/ folder of the jar, and in the MANIFEST.MF...
Flamingo is a nice swing ribbon (word 2016-like).

Comment: What is the full package name for view.BookWindow class?

Comment: @Ivan I made a screenshot, I think it's simply "view"

Comment: Maybe it is unrelated but I see duplicated byte-buddy, byte-buddy-agent and mockito-core in list of dependencies on a screenshot. Are you sure that all dependencies used in your code are included? I've tried building jar using Intellij wizard on my project and it works.

Comment: Have you changed the actual manifest file from the created jar artifact? can you run view.BookWindow class via main method from IDE using Application Run/Debug Configuration? Try also build and run the jar by Maven and compare the result. I also see there is another source root in your project in `src/com` folder. Such layout doesn't look correct to me. What is that folder for? Can you move it to `src/main/java` standard Maven location?

Comment: @Andrey I updated my question, I didn't changed the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I did it. I still don't know why neither  the flamingo jar nor the main class wern't available, but I made it work by creating a new artifact in intellij having all the jars outside the project's jar. all the dependencies outside. I will the next time adopt the continuous integration and thus I will alwayq have a working jar ready ! elle